# Android: Immersive Sticky mode creates margins on left and right of screen

Tags: android, canvas, fullscreen, mode

I've been searching for a while now and did not find any solution for my problem, so i decided to ask you guys here. Probably the solution is pretty simple, i'm just too blind to see it.

I'm creating a little game for android, in which i have to draw some lines on a bitmap. I want to use the app in full-screen mode (without status bar and without navigation bar). So i'm using the "Immersive Sticky Mode", which hides those bars.

My problem is, that i always got a little margin on the left and right of the display, which i cant use. I made some screenshots, to illustrate the problem. (I pasted the screenshots in paint on a black background, so you can see the edges of the screen).

Here's a link to the screenshot: http://www.directupload.net/file/d/4091/tgnoufx5_jpg.htm

In this activity, one can draw an arbitrary line on the display (which is not meaningful for the problem, but it helps to explain it).
As you can see, if i draw line to the top or bottom of the screen, it gets correctly drawn. If i draw a line to the right or left, the display is "limited" and i get margins, where the line cannot be drawn.

Here's the code I'm using:

-XML-Code of the Activity:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
```

-Corresponding Java-Code:

```
public class DrawActivity extends Activity implements View.OnTouchListener {

private ImageView drawContainer;
private Bitmap bitmap; 
private Canvas canvas; 


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    toggleHideyBar(2);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawtrack);
    drawContainer = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    drawContainer.setOnTouchListener(this);



    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
    int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

    drawContainer.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}


public void toggleHideyBar(int ch) {


    int uiOptions = getWindow().getDecorView().getSystemUiVisibility();
    int newUiOptions = uiOptions;


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) {
        newUiOptions ^= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
    }


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
        newUiOptions ^= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 18 && ch == 1) {
        newUiOptions ^= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE;
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 18 && ch == 2) {
        newUiOptions ^= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
    }

    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(newUiOptions);
}
```

EDIT: i can display simple textView-Fields at those margins, so maybe the problem is caused by the bitmap or the Activity-XML (Layout)? Still didn't figure it out...

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution to my problem. When hiding display decors (like status and navigation bar), one needs to use

```
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRealMetrics(displaymetrics);
```

instead of

```
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
```

According to the Android-API, `getMetrics()` includes system decorations, while `getRealMetrics()` excludes them. So when using the immersive mode, one should consider this. [Android API: Display](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getRealSize%28android.graphics.Point%29)